# SSL between web apps on same machine

Tags: java, security, ssl

I have two java web applications installed on the same machine communicating over HTTP, security is a big concern because application A validates the license of application B.

I believe that it doesn't make sense to enable HTTPS as we probably can't hide application A private key, making HTTPS useless.

Is there a way to enable HTTPS in this scenario so that it makes sense to use it? I'm not sure if it's relevant but application A is pretty small so probably concealing the private key is even more difficult.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a good reason to do this, or for tips on how to hide the keys between the applications? Hiding can be done with isolation like VM, containers or jails (depending on your OS and requirements). You can also pack & encrypt the executable to hide the key with something like VMProtect.

Comment: Mostly if there is good reason to do this, this is what I fail to find, but indeed if the answer is that it makes sense to use it, would any of these methods keep a hacker out for more than 4 hours. I mean any hidding mechanism that I might use, if I need the key for SSL available to the server, would it be that hard for anyone with access to that machine to find it very fast?

Comment: I don't see a reason for it, so long as you use the loopback device. If a hacker gains enough access to dump packets from `lo`, they most likely already have `root` on that machine.

Comment: The applications are not installed on a server, they come as a windows installer on a dvd, so yes a hacker would have all the time he needs, it's just a question of how hard would it be for him to bypass HTTPS and would it make life significantly harder to less experienced hackers.